# Problem restoring from a CWM backup

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y (galaxy Young) GT-S5360 La Fleur edition with Android ver 2.3.6

Following [method 1B given here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/ClockworkMod_Recovery), I first found an CWM update.zip file for my phone model [from here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2068309)

I also took a backup after booting into the recovery screen using this update.zip file

It created a clockworkmod\backup\2011-05-17.17.52.06 folder and this folder contains the following files:

.android_secure.vfat.tar   2 KB
cache.rfs.tar             60 KB
data.rfs.tar          166284 KB
nandroid.md5               1 KB
system.rfs.tar        216314 KB

Using the [tutorial here](http://www.droidthunder.com/install-android-7-0-nougat-rom-on-galaxy-y-gt-s5360/), I managed to download android 7 nougat ROM, and it boots and works file (up to now, sometimes shows a crash message, not sure where it's from)

I tried going into recovery mode again (it turns out after after following all the steps of the tutorial above, when I press power+home+Volume up to go to the recovery screen, the built in recovery screen has already been replaced by the CWM one for good, but I think it's probably not important for now) and when I go to the restore option, the restore process completes almost immediately (so I suspect it is failing for some reason, but I can't see any relevant log message)

Then the screen goes back to the CWM recovery menu, and if I select restart system it boots back into the nougat 7 ROM

How do I restore my phone to my previous state (that is, back to gingerbread) using CWM recovery backup?

Comment: You can find logs of the process at `/cache/recovery/last_log`. That would be helpful to see what's going on. If you could paste it to a site such as pastebin.com or which ever you choose then attach the link to your post.

Comment: @BoLawSon Thanks I'n not at that computer anymore I'll post an update as soon as I get a chance to get back at it

Comment: Sounds good, just a heads up the last_log file is within your GT-S5360.